# Is analogWrite() not affected by blocking codes and/or Interrupts?

Tags: analogwrite

Well just as the question say, is the analogWrite() function will continue generating near-consistent PWM when it encounters blocking codes or signal interrupts?

Is it the same case for both the classic arduinos(atmega chips) and the new arduinos(SAMD21 chips).

If analogWrite() does get affected by blocking codes, is there a way to create a uninterruptible PWM signal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is the analogWrite() function 
>   continue generating near-consistent PWM when it encounters blocking
>   codes or signal interrupts?

Yes for 'hardware' PWM used by analogWrite on AVR and SAMD Arduinos. The hardware PWM is handled by wave output of Timers, which are MCU peripherals running independently from CPU and other MCU peripherals.

> Is it the same case for both the classic arduinos(atmega chips) and
>   the new arduinos(SAMD21 chips).

yes

> If analogWrite() does get affected by blocking codes, is there a way
>   to create a uninterruptible PWM signal?

N/A